# ¿Se puede restablecer los valores de instalación de xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp

el problema que tengo es que no recuerdo la contraseña del usuario root de XAMPP MySQL y no puedo ingresar, intente entrar por --skip-grant-tables y cambiar la contraseña para poder entrar, ya estoy dentro pero no puedo modificar nada de privilegios como lo puedo resolver??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes reeestablecer pero perderias tus bases de datos creo

Comment: Ya probaste ejecutando comandos desde el Shell? Mirate este tutorial https://platzi.com/tutoriales/1272-sql-mysql/3035-recuperar-usuario-root-cuando-olvidas-contrasena/

Comment: Prueba a seguir algunos de los pasos de esta página:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566453/resetting-mysql-root-password-with-xampp-on-localhost